# How to output net group command in list format in batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm using the `net group "Groupname" /domain` command which outputs a bunch of users in the group in the format of 3 columns. There are spaces between the columns.

How do I output the command so that there is one user per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attempt something before asking next time.

Assuming the output of the command is roughly:

```
bossMan    Arescet    Ice
superuser  lazyWorker Dog 
(etc...)
```

As i am unsure of the output of this file from where I'm writing this, I don't know if a prefix to the output is given that needs to be ignored.

```
:: First attempt with a single line;
for /f %%G in ('net group "Groupname" /domain') do (echo %%G)
```

Now i prefer using files by habit of backups and odd character handling so i would use this, although it is 3 lines and writes to a file;

```
:: Write the output of your command into a file:
net group "Groupname" /domain >userList.temp

:: Split the content by spaces, and write each space separated token.
:: Column 1 is %%~G, 2 is %%~H, 3 is %%~I. 
for /f %%G in (userList.tmp) do (
    echo %%~G
    echo %%~H
    echo %%~I
)

:: Cleanup the temp file;
del "userList.temp"
```

Of course `>>output.ext` can be applied individually to `%%~G %%~H %%~I`, or a call with that specified column of the current line.

Comment: Doing this only outputs the first column, not the second and third.

Comment: Fixed, don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use tokens=1,2,3 option

```
echo off
:: Write the output of your command into a file:
net group "Groupname" /domain >userList.temp

:: Split the content by spaces, and write each space separated token.
:: Column 1 is %%~G, 2 is %%~H, 3 is %%~I. 
for /f "skip=8 tokens=1,2,3" %%G in (userList.temp) do (
    echo %%G
    echo %%H
    echo %%I
)

:: Cleanup the temp file;
del "userList.temp"
pause
echo on
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the heavy lifting creating this script, it worked very nicely.
However I wanted to evaluate a number of groups so I added in the ability to pass the group as an argument and write the output to a file.  Very minor tweaks on the existing solution.

```
echo off
set GRP_NM=%1
:: Write the output of your command into a file:
net group "%GRP_NM%" /domain >userList.temp

:: Split the content by spaces, and write each space separated token.
:: Column 1 is %%~G, 2 is %%~H, 3 is %%~I. 
echo UserName > %GRP_NM%_userlist.txt
for /f "skip=8 tokens=1,2,3" %%G in (userList.temp) do (
    echo %%~G >> %GRP_NM%_userlist.txt
    echo %%~H >> %GRP_NM%_userlist.txt
    echo %%~I >> %GRP_NM%_userlist.txt

)

:: Cleanup the temp file;
del "userList.temp"
::pause
echo on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FOR 'command' option directly to do this without the temporary file.

**The simple version** extracting only usernames in a given group on the command line goes like this:

```
@ECHO off
CLS
::Get the group name from the command line
IF not "%1"=="" SET str_Grp-Nm=%1
IF not "%1"=="" ^> Given group name: '%str_Grp-Nm%'.
IF not DEFINED str_Grp-Nm SET str_Grp-Nm=Default_group
::Remove double quotes if any.
SET str_Grp-Nm=%str_Grp-Nm:"=%
::Default DOS-language: EN-US/ENU ^(Engels, USA^)
  SET str_LastLn=The command completed

ECHO User names in group name;%str_Grp-Nm%>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
::Split the content in three columns; column 1 is %%~g, 2 is %%~h and 3 is %%~i. 
FOR /f "skip=8 tokens=1,2,3" %%g IN ('NET group "%str_Grp-Nm%" /domain') DO (
  rem Skip the last line 'The command completed successfully.'. Note; this last line is language dependent, in Dutch the last line is: 'De opdracht is voltooid.'.
  IF /i not "%%~g %%~h %%~i"=="%str_LastLn%" (
    ECHO ^> Found username '%%~g':
      ECHO %%~g>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
    IF not '%%~h'=='' ECHO ^> Found username '%%~h':
      IF not '%%~h'=='' ECHO %%~h>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
    IF not '%%~i'=='' ECHO ^> Found username '%%~i':
      IF not '%%~i'=='' ECHO %%~i>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO * %%~g %%~h %%~i successfully!
  )
)
IF exist "%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv" START "This quoted line is needed for %OS%" "%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"

::Cleanup the environment...
SET str_Grp-Nm=
SET str_LastLn=
```

**An expanded version**, also extracting the full username and detecting the, in my case Dutch, DOS-language.
Note: The DOS language *could* be different from your OS-language, especially in multilingual-systems.

```
@ECHO off
CLS
::Get the group name from the command line
IF not "%1"=="" SET str_Grp-Nm=%1
IF not "%1"=="" ECHO ^> Given group name: '%str_Grp-Nm%'.
IF not DEFINED str_Grp-Nm SET str_Grp-Nm=Default_group
::Remove double quotes if any.
SET str_Grp-Nm=%str_Grp-Nm:"=%
::Default DOS-language: EN-US/ENU ^(Engels, USA^)
  SET str_Usr-Fn=Full Name
  SET str_Usr-Un=UserName
  SET str_LastLn=The command completed
::Detect DOS-language: NL-NL/NLD ^(Nederlands, Nederland^)
NET user %UserName% /domain | FIND /i "vOltoOid.">NUL &IF not ErrorLevel 1 (
  ECHO ^> DOS-language: NL-NL/NLD ^(Nederlands, Nederland^) detected.
  SET str_Usr-Fn=Volledige naam
  SET str_Usr-Un=Gebruikersnaam
  SET str_LastLn=De opdracht is
)

ECHO * Check for usernames in group: '%str_Grp-Nm%'
ECHO Press any key to continue, Ctrl+C to quit.
  PAUSE > NUL
  ::Or continue afther...   TimeOut /t 33
ECHO Group name;%str_Grp-Nm%>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
ECHO %str_Usr-Un%;%str_Usr-Fn%>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
::Split the content in three columns; column 1 is %%~g, 2 is %%~h and 3 is %%~i. 
FOR /f "skip=8 tokens=1,2,3" %%g IN ('NET group "%str_Grp-Nm%" /domain') DO (
  rem Skip the last line 'The command completed successfully.'. Note; this last line is language dependent, in Dutch the last line is: 'De opdracht is voltooid.'.
  IF /i not "%%~g %%~h %%~i"=="%str_LastLn%" (
    ECHO ^> Check '%%~g':
      REM Get the 'Full Name' from the UserName by using: 'NET user %%~g /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%"'. Use double qoutes to get the pipe-action in the FOR-command. Because there is a space in 'Full Name' a search for "name" does not give the correct result (2 ànd 3 columns).
      FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~g /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO %%~g;%%v>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
      FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~g /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO   %str_Usr-Un%; '%%~g'; %str_Usr-Fn%; "%%v".
    IF not '%%~h'=='' ECHO ^> Check '%%~h':
      IF not '%%~h'=='' FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~h /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO %%~h;%%v>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
      IF not '%%~h'=='' FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~h /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO   %str_Usr-Un%; '%%~h'; %str_Usr-Fn%; "%%v".
    IF not '%%~i'=='' ECHO ^> Check '%%~i':
      IF not '%%~i'=='' FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~i /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO %%~i;%%v>>"%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"
      IF not '%%~i'=='' FOR /f "tokens=2,*" %%u IN ('"NET user %%~i /domain | FIND /i "%str_Usr-Fn%""') DO ECHO   %str_Usr-Un%; '%%~i'; %str_Usr-Fn%; "%%v".
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO * %%~g %%~h %%~i successfully!
  )
)
IF exist "%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv" START "This quoted line is needed for %OS%" "%~dpn0 - %str_Grp-Nm%.csv"

::Cleanup the environment...
SET str_Grp-Nm=
SET str_Usr-Fn=
SET str_Usr-Un=
SET str_LastLn=
```

**Note:** You can extract more information from the combination *NET user* and *FIND*, basically following the syntax below here.

```
NET user <username> /domain | FIND /i "<search string>"
```

And there is much more possible by using Visual Basic. But those are other storys ;o)

Good luck!